# Polyglossia, french, decimal separator mistake in math mode

Tags: math-mode, polyglossia

There is a problem with a misplaced space using `Polyglossia` and `french` in math mode using decimal separator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\begin{document}

$5.3$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't it be `5,3`?

Comment: No problem with TeXLive 2015. There is no space with `xelatex`, apart from Bernard's remark about the `,` instead of `.`

Comment: But here is a space with `lualatex` :-(

Comment: With 5,3 one cumuls both problems `5 , 3` with two bad spaces. I use TeXLive 2014 and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: No problem with LuaLaTeX if you use `\numprint{5.3}` ->  `5,3` (numprint package) or `\num{5.3}` from `siunitx` which outputs `5.3` or 5,3` depending on how you configure it.

Comment: @Bernard: I've just checked with direct `5.3` and `ngerman` instead of `french`, it's no problem either with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. Apparently, there is really a problem with `polyglossia` for French language and lualatex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use `siunitx` and its `\num` macro, apply the relevant options instead of directly type in the number.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage[copy-decimal-marker=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\num{5,3}

\end{document}
```

This works for `xelatex` and `lualatex` with no (apparent) difference.

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[local=FR]{siunitx}`, works for both 5.3 et 5,3. I hopped a solution without the `num{}` strainght.

Comment: @Tarass: I sometimes type multi-style (. and ,), so I need the `copy` way.