# Serif fonts with beamer and polyglossia

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex, polyglossia

I'm using this code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Blabla}
Blabla $x$ blabla 2,5 blabla $2,5$.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Without polyglossia, I get this result.

[image: without polyglossia]

With polyglossia, I get this result.

[image]

The serif font isn't used inside block (only the title). I was expecting the same result with polyglossia or without.

There is also bad spacing with comma in 2,5 in math mode ... but it is another problem.

Comment: for the comma problem, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256391/polyglossia-french-decimal-separator-mistake-in-math-mode

Comment: Thx, I was using icomma but it's not working fine with polyglossia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to switch to serif font before loading `polyglossia`

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Blabla}
Blabla $x$ blabla 2,5 blabla $2,5$.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]